# Why does --uid option leads to permission denied error when running uWSGI on Alipne?

Tags: docker, uwsgi

I've got a simple Flask app in Alpine:3.10 based container and I want to run it with uWSGI. Thing is, when I run it specifying the --uid argument:

```
CMD [ "uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:80", \
               "--uid", "uwsgi", \
               "--plugins", "python3", \
               "--protocol", "http", \
               "--module", "owo.app:app", \
               "-p", "4", \
               "--enable-threads"]
```

It logs permission denied error and exits with code 1:

```
ind(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 769]
```

But if I comment the *--uid* argument, it warns me that I run it as root (which is bad), but runs fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `root` can bind to ports < 1024. You should change your `uwsgi` command line to run on something other than port 80, e.g:

```
CMD [ "uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:8080", \
               "--uid", "uwsgi", \
               "--plugins", "python3", \
               "--protocol", "http", \
               "--module", "owo.app:app", \
               "-p", "4", \
               "--enable-threads"]
```

It doesn't matter what port you run on inside your container, because you can always map this to port 80 on your host when you `docker run` your container (`docker run -p 80:8080 ...`).